# Extract folder and keep regex group order intact

Tags: regex

Given te following strings:

```
/folder/subfolder/all
/folder/subfolder/all?a=b
/folder/anothersubfolder/all?a=b
/folder/all
/folder/all?a=b
/folder/anothersubfolder
/folder/anothersubfolder/all
/folder
```

The subfolder "all" is predefined and needs to be extracted seperatetly from the any other subfolder that may or may not exist in the string.

A regex like

```
^\/(folder)(\/[^/?]*)?(\/[^/?]*)?(\?.*)?$
```

does not work for me. The group containing the different folders should be fixed. With this regex the subfolder "all" is either in group 2 or 3.

The results of the regex should be something like:

- Group 1: /folder (mandatory can only be "/folder")
- Group 2: /subfolder (optional can be any string except "/all")
- Group 3: /all (optional can only be "/all")
- Group 4: ?a=b (optional any set of parameters)

Comment: Note that is doesn't seem useful to group "folder" since its content will always be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^\/(folder)((?:\/(?!all)[^/?]*)?)((?:\/all)?)((?:\?.*)?)$`

```
[["folder", "/subfolder",        "/all", ""    ],
 ["folder", "/subfolder",        "/all", "?a=b"],
 ["folder", "/anothersubfolder", "/all", "?a=b"],
 ["folder", "",                  "/all", ""    ],
 ["folder", "",                  "/all", "?a=b"],
 ["folder", "/anothersubfolder", "",     ""    ],
 ["folder", "/anothersubfolder", "/all", ""    ],
 ["folder", "",                  "",     ""    ]]
```

There are two main tricks here:

1. Non-capturing groups `?:` which tell the regex engine not to hold on to a match, but still use it for clumping regex parts together. It lets us do things like `((?:stuff)?)`, which makes a mandatory group that can be empty.
2. Negative lookahead `?!` which tells the regex to NOT match a certain pattern. So in this case `(?!all)` says that "all" can't be in the second directory block. (note: this means the second directory can't start with "all")

Comment: I think you could simplify `((?:\/all)?)` into `(\/all)?` for the same result, although it might change the result from the empty string to a null/undefined value depending on the language.

Comment: @Aaron, exactly. It's the choice between empty-string and null/undefined. Guess it depends which is better for OP.